Why is my whole armature moving when I keyframe an object?
I'm working with a character rig for a game I'm making, and I want to have separate idle animations. I'd like to have one animation where the character is holding their Katanas, and another where the pistols are being wielded instead. However, when I try to position the Katana object near the hand, the entire armature moves and rotates with it.
Here's what the armature looks like before I position anything (what it should normally look like)

Here's what it looks like before I keyframe

And here's what it looks like after I keyframe

I'd like to have just the object be affected by the keyframe, and not the entire body and armature. This is my first time modeling a character, so I apologize if I just accidentally ticked something I shouldn't have. If it helps any, I modeled the character myself, and rigged it on the Mixamo website. If more info or screenshots are needed, please let me know.

I think the issue was caused by trying to move two objects under one action animation. Does anyone have a simple way around this?
